# Why time_since_epoch() from a std::filesystem::file_time_type is negative?

Tags: c++, time, filesystems, c++-chrono

Why does the following code output a negative number?

[coliru link](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f3db9617de6312e) to see and compile the code yourself.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Now: "
            << std::filesystem::file_time_type::clock().now().time_since_epoch().count()
            << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

```
Output:

Now: -4818978774392359625
```

Answer (score 11):

The epoch for libstdc++'s `std::filesystem::file_time_type::clock()` appears to be [2174-01-01 00:00:00 UTC](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/chrono#L3280) therefore a negative count for current dates is not unexpected.

Comment: mamma mia! why 2174!!! oh god

Comment: @Dee it's the midpoint of `1901-2446`

Comment: And what's the special meaning around dat 2446 ?

Comment: @Jesko see under [Inode Timestamps](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout), ext4 uses a 34-bit second counter giving a range of about 544.5 years, 1901 + 544 is just under 2446 (the actual range is `1901-12-13` to `2446-05-10`)

Comment: From that I see now, that the (raw?) time seems not to be portable between systems (as I would expect using std::filesystem) ... so writing it into a file and using it elsewhere is no good idea :-( ok one could translate it into local time and output that - with all these calculations in between ...

Comment: No, it's not portable, it'll generally be something related to the underlying os filesystem time storage